# Why are my indoor grown Loquat saplings, grown from seeds, getting wilted and blackened leaves and dying?

Tags: diseases, leaves, fruit-trees, indoors, greenhouse

I would like to apologise for the fact that I am not a good or experienced gardener.

I had some loquat seeds and I thought I'd try to grow them, now they have sprouted and grown leaves I re-potted them into larger separate pots(mostly).

Winter has come around, I had kept them in my back garden but because the trays the pots were in to catch the extra water were literally full of ice, I brought the trays and pots into my "Green House."
It had a translucent, insulating roof and top half of the walls but due to the weakness of the roof it was replaced with an opaque roof. So only the top half of the wall is translucent.
I moved the loquats inside, it is less cold but there is less light.

Now some of the leaves are withered and black, the smaller saplings barely have roots. I have been watering them with a fertiliser. Using the instructions on the box.

I don't know if it is a disease or the lack of light causing the leaves to wilt. I have also been told that it could be just the natural leaf shedding process, but I wasn't sure if saplings do that.

I am just worried about them and don't want them to die.

Here are some pictures of my plants, set-up and fertiliser:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE:
In a few days I am going to move them to a place outside where the sun will be able to hit them and they will not be in shadow.
I am going to construct a sort of green house from insulating translucent planes I had lying around in case of very cold weather and I will probably get an outdoor temperature sensor.
I discovered something new however, there were tiny slugs attacking the leaves of some of the plants and a tiny snail on another one, these where the plants with holes in the leaves. The other plants that had wilted and withered brown and black leaves either have a disease or fungus. I googled it and it looked similar to Verticillium Wilt, but I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what part of the world you are in, although you must be in the northern hemisphere since you mention ice and cold weather arriving. Loquat trees are not deciduous, so leaf loss should not occur during winter; they are hardy down to minus 10degC, but obviously small ones won't be as hardy as that.

One piece of advice is to stop fertilising immediately - it is not growing season, it's winter, so fertiliser should not be given before mid spring at the earliest. Your photos are rather dark, but I can see one or two brown edged holes in one leaf which might mean you had or have a pest causing those, or they might be caused by fungal or bacterial issues - check the backs of the leaves closely to see if there's anything there that shouldn't be. Because the photos are dark, its also impossible to tell how wet the soil is in the pots - don't water them too much during winter, only when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch. The other question I have is, where you've moved them to, is it a closed environment, i.e, a closed door and no airflow otherwise? If it is, this might be causing problems, as might significantly reduced light levels - if you are in the UK for instance, day length is almost at its shortest with only 7 hours of daylight anyway, so keeping them somewhere darker isn't ideal, but better than letting them freeze to death if temperatures outdoors are very low.

UPDATE: If you live in London, since the cold snap a couple of weeks back, the overnight temperatures have not fallen below about 6 degrees C, not cold enough for freezing. On re-reading your question, I note you say you observed the water sitting in the outer trays the pots were in froze - the thing to say about that is, never leave your saplings sitting in water, either dispense with the trays over winter altogether or empty them out daily. Leaving them sitting in water over winter will encourage fungal diseases and root rots. Unless you live in a particularly cold part of outer London, find a spot in your garden that is sheltered, like against the house wall especially if its south facing, preferably gets sun if there is any, and cluster the pots together. A cold frame would be useful for extra protection, but a sheet of glass propped over the pots against the wall would help protect them. Or use horticultural fleece to put over them when it's cold, but this must not be left in place all winter, remove it during the day. If the temperature during January and February falls to below freezing day and night, which would be zero or below, very rare here, they will need to be moved inside your 'greenhouse' until the freezing spell passes, when you can put them back outside again. As for bacterial or fungal infection, treatments for both would not be the same, but the truth is, there are no effective fungicides available for amateur use in the UK anyway. Adding an extra photo or two of some of the plants taken outside in bright daylight might be helpful to see what's going on, but I suspect the problems you are seeing are likely due to overly wet,cold soil, inappropriate use of fertiliser, and choosing to grow the seeds at the wrong end of the  year - you may be lucky and get some of them through till spring next year with care. If you do not have a weather station or an outdoor thermometer, it might be worth investing in one; Amazon does a fairly cheap indoor/outdoor one so you know what the temperature is both inside and outside without actually going outside, and you'd be able to monitor whether the plants need extra protection because of low temperatures more easily.

Comment: I live in london, They are in a closed area with very little air flow. 
I could try and find a lighter area with better air flow.
i will look for any fungus or bacterial issue, if i find something i will post it, 
is there a one solution fits all for fungus and bacteria or do specific infections need specific solutions?

Comment: By the look of your blue fertilizer, you followed Miracle Gro dilutions and created a brew **too concentrated**.  Even when you do return to fertilizing in Spring. Now, aren't you going to bring your tropical pants into your house?

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: I updated the question
Thank you so much, i found some pests and disposed of them, I don't know much about the disease affecting the others but i can only hope for the best.